# How to substract rows from one table from another only once

Tags: sql, oracle, subtraction

I'm working for a university project, and I have the following question:
I have 2 tables in a Oracle DB... I need to select those rows from table1, which are not included in table2... But the main problem is that I need to exclude that rows from table2 wich was selected once... For example:

```
Table1                       Table2                      ResultTable
id  | Number | Letter        id  | Number | Letter       id  | Number | Letter
_____________________        _____________________       _____________________
1        4        S          1       6        G          2        2        P 
2        2        P          2       8        B          3        5        B
3        5        B          3       4        S          4        4        S
4        4        S          4       1        A          6        2        P
5        1        A          5       1        H
6        2        P          6       2        X
```

So, how you see it, if one row from Table1 has a "twin" in Table2, they both are excluded.

Comment: Hi, can I clarify the question please?
You are matching only on Number and Letter (that is, you don't match on Id).
And each entry in Table2 only excludes one entry from Table1 (so with 4 S, the row in Table1 with id=1 is excluded by row with id=3 in Table2, but id=4 in Table1 is not ?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking only to cancel the twins. Like row with id = 1 from Table1 is canceled with row with id = 3 in Table2(also rowid = 5 from Table1 is canceled by rowid = 4 from Table2), but the row with id = 4 Table1 (same number and letter 4 S), must be returned in result, 'cause is not been canceled by any row in Table2...

Comment: So a row in table1 is only "cancelled" if the `id` in table2 is higher than the one in table1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most thorough query is this:

```
SELECT table1.id,
       table1.digit,
       table1.letter
  FROM ( SELECT id,
                digit,
                letter,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY digit, letter ORDER BY id) rn
           FROM table1
       ) table1
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT id,
                digit,
                letter,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY digit, letter ORDER BY id) rn
           FROM table2
       ) table2
    ON table2.digit = table1.digit
   AND table2.letter = table1.letter
   AND table2.rn = table1.rn
 WHERE table2.id IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY table1.id
;
```

which gives each record in `table1` and `table2` a "row number" within its group of "twins". For example, this:

```
SELECT id,
       digit,
       letter,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY digit, letter ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM table1
 ORDER
    BY table1.id
;
```

returns this:

```
        ID      DIGIT LETT         RN
---------- ---------- ---- ----------
         1          4 S             1
         2          2 P             1
         3          5 B             1
         4          4 S             2     -- second row with 4 S
         5          1 A             1
         6          2 P             2     -- second row with 2 P
```

That said, if you know that no `(digit, letter)` can ever appear more than once in `table2`, you can simplify this considerably by using `EXISTS` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id,
       digit,
       letter
  FROM table1 table1a
 WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM table1
           WHERE digit = table1a.digit
             AND letter = table1a.letter
             AND id < table1a.id
        )
    OR NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM table2
           WHERE digit = table1a.digit
             AND letter = table1a.letter
        )
;
```

Comment: Thanks ruakh, that's exact querry I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Break it into parts.

Perhaps you have an EOR - Exclusive OR.

So you might have
`(condition1

    OR

    condition2)

    AND NOT

(condition1 AND condition2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Oracle MINUS keyword, which does exactly what you're asking for.  See http://oreilly.com/catalog/mastorasql/chapter/ch07.html for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see how to do what you want with one SQL SELECT.

I think you'll need a temporary table, and several statements.

Call it `tmpResults`, with `id1` and `id2`, which match the `id` from `Table1` and the `id` from `Table2` respectively.

```
-- get matched rows - this is too many, we'll delete some later.

INSERT INTO tmpResults (id1, id2)
  SELECT Table1.id id1, Table2.id id2 
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
         ON Table1.Number = Table2.Number AND Table1.Letter = Table2.Letter;

-- Delete where Table1 has matched more than 1 row
DELETE tmpResults 
   WHERE rowid IN
     (SELECT tmpResults.RowId 
          FROM tmpResults 
           INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT id1, MAX(id2) id2m FROM tmpResults GROUP BY id1 HAVING count(*) > 1) m1
           ON tmpResults.id1 = m1.id1 AND tmpResults.id2 = m1.id2m );

-- Delete where Table2 has matched more than 1 row
DELETE tmpResults
  WHERE rowid IN
    (SELECT tmpResults.RowId
       FROM tmpResults
          INNER JOIN 
             (SELECT MAX(id1) id1m, id2 FROM tmpResults GROUP BY id2 HAVING count(*) >1) m2
          ON tmpResults.id1 = m2.id1m AND tmpResults.id2 = m2.id2 );

-- now tmpResults should have unique matches only, so we want Table1 where there is no match
SELECT Table1.* 
  FROM Table1 
    LEFT JOIN tmpResults
      ON table1.id = tmpResults.id1
    WHERE tmpResults.id2 IS NULL;
```